# get all comments including its votes for a post

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following three tables in `mysql`.

> postid | post_content => **posts**
>
> commentid | post | comment_content => **comments**
>
> commentvoteid | comment | voter => **comment_votes**

I want to fetch all the `comments`, `counting its votes` for a `post`.

> commentid | comment_content | comment_votes => **my_result**

I have tried the following query but not getting the desired result.

```
SELECT commentid,comment_content,count_comments.total AS comment_votes
FROM comments
INNER JOIN(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM comment_votes WHERE comment=comments.commentid) AS count_comments
WHERE post={$postId}
```

Is it possible to fetch the result as I wanted? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT commentid,comment_content,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM comments
INNER JOIN comment_votes ON (comment_votes.comment=comments.commentid)
WHERE post={$postId}
GROUP BY commentid;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly but I `LEFT JOIN`ed to grab the comments that are not available in `comment_votes` yet.

Answer (score 2):

The method that you are trying uses a correlated subquery.  You can do this, but the correlated subquery needs to go into the `select` clause:

```
SELECT c.commentid, c.comment_content,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_votes cv WHERE cv.comment = c.commentid
       ) AS comment_votes
FROM comments c
WHERE post={$postId};
```

Normally, I much prefer the `group by` approach but sometimes in MySQL this can be faster.

Comment: It worked but I choosed the answer by @mesutozer as you referred `group by`, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
select a.commentid, a.comment_content, count(b.*) as total from (
select commentid, comment_content from comments where post={$postId}) a
join comment_votes b on b.comment = a.commentid
group by a.commentid, a.comment_content;
```